# print n character after pattern match

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

I have line say

```
jan 02:12:00 YRU QRS : ASP.net Bird
feb 02:12:00 YRU QRS : ASP.net Dog
```

I want a script to have a pattern search of `ASP.NET` and print the 10 Characters from it in each line , So that it would involve both `Bird` and `Dog`

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question could be improved by posting examples of the code you've tried and the output they produced. StackOverflow is about helping people, but it's not about doing it for them. Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'm/asp\.net\s+(.{0,10})/i && print "$1\n"' infile
```

That yields:

```
Bird
Dog
```

---

**EDIT** to explain the syntax of the `perl` one-liner:

`m/.../i` tries to match a regular expression with the whole line. The `i` flag ignores the case. The regular expression is the literal `asp.net` plus spaces plus any number of characters between 0 and 10 in greedy way. If that succeeds execute the following instruction that prints what matched between parens.

Comment: Awesome Birei, Thanks can you please take me through the syntax. It would help me world of good.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /ASP.net (.{0,10})/'
```

Comment: This would be better if you explained the `-l` option (it is a trifle unusual).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think `-l` is far from unusual, although I do agree that this solution is terse to the point of rudeness.

Comment: @Borodin: I guess unusualness is in the eye of the beholder; I've never used `-l` that I can remember and had to look it up to know what it does (though it might sometimes be useful, if I could remember to use it), and I've only been programming in Perl for about twenty years now.  However, there are so many sub-dialects of Perl, it maybe isn't indicative of anything except that it is a big language/program with lots of options that not everyone uses all the time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It is particularly prevalent in one-liners as `-ln` or `-lp`, as it avoids the need to `chomp` input and to write an explicit `"\n"` on `print` statements. `perl -lne` is pretty much an idiom, as you will see if you google it.

Answer (score 3):

awk one-liner:

```
awk -F'ASP\\.net' '{print substr($2,0,10)}' file
```

Note that this will print 10 chars **immediately** after `ASP.net`, which means, starting from the `space`. if you don't want the space, use the line below:

```
 awk -F'ASP\\.net ' '{print substr($2,0,10)}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU and BSD greps have a nice extension `--only-matching`, or `-o`, which will output only the part of the line you match:

```
grep -Eio 'asp\.net.{0,10}' <<< 'jan 02:12:00 YRU QRS : ASP.net Bird
feb 02:12:00 YRU QRS : ASP.net Dog'
ASP.net Bird
ASP.net Dog
```

Bash can do this with its regular expression functionality, though it's probably better if you turn on case-insensitive matching first:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
while read; do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ asp\.net(.{0,10}) ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done <<< 'jan 02:12:00 YRU QRS : ASP.net Bird
feb 02:12:00 YRU QRS : ASP.net Dog'
 Bird
 Dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the text inside a file "input.txt" the following one-liner will do the job:

```
cat input.txt | awk '/ASP\.net/ {print substr($0, index($0,"ASP.net") + length("ASP.net"), 10)}'
```

Explanation:

- On lines that contain the text "ASP.net"
- print 10 characters
- starting right after the location of "ASP.net"

Comment: No [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) is required: `awk` can take the filename as an argument directly. (And if it couldn't, you could just do `< input.txt`.)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/.*ASP\.net(.{,10}).*/s//\1/p' file
```